# Probability of each person writing code--in a certain language

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am little lost with this problem. Not sure which formulas to use

A project was implemented by three developers: *Pat*, *Jon*, and *Maria*. They used four languages: *C*, *C++*, *Python*, and *JavaScript*. The table summarizes what fraction of the code was written by each person in each language.
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\text{name} & \text{C} & \text{C++} & \text{Python} & \text{JavaScript}\\
\hline
\text{Pat} & 5/24 &1/8 &1/6& 0\\
\text{Jon} &1/24& 1/8& 1/12& 0\\
\text{Maria} & 0& 0& 1/12 &1/6\\
\end{array}$$

(a) Who is most likely to be the author of that piece of code?

(b) Who is most likely to be the author given that it was written in JS?

(c) Who is most likely to be the author given that it was written in C or C++?

(d) What is the probability that it was written by Jon? Does the probability change if we know
that the code is in Python? Are the events Python and Jon independent or not?

(e) Are the events Pat and C independent?

(f) The same question for Maria and JS.

For $a$: wouldn't Pat be the author of the piece written in C, Jon for C++, and Maria for JS? Is there actual computing for this question or do you just know by looking at the chart

$b$: Maria

$c$: would if be Jon because he did less work?

Comment: Looks like you should be using [Bayes' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) for the questions that involve phrases like "given $X$ is true". Also refer to the definition of [independent events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29).

Comment: @eigenchris thanks much that actually helps a lot

Comment: For part a you have to summarize the proportions of each row. After that compare the results. Note that the sum of all proportions is 1.

Comment: @calculus can you explain more?

Comment: The sum of the first row is the proportion of pat´s work of the whole code. This is $\frac{5}{24}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{6}=0.5$; Jan:0.25;Maria:0.25. Thus the piece of the code is most likely written by pat.

Comment: I think at least part of the "I'm lost" phenomenon is due to the fact that the topic of this word problem is phenomenally ill-defined and ill-chosen. I've tried to express this a bit more constructively in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

**(a)**

You just need to sum the portions.

$P(Pat)=\frac{5}{24}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{2}\\
P(Jon)=\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{12}=\frac{1}{4}\\
P(Maria)=\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{4}$

So it's most likely that, given a piece of code, Pat wrote it.

**(b)**

It's *Maria*, who's the only one who wrote in *JS*

**(c)**

Following the same as in (a), $P(Pat\mid C \cap C\verb !++!) \geq P(Jon\mid C \cap C\verb !++!) \geq P(Maria\mid C \cap  C \verb !++!)$

So it's *Pat*

**(d)**

Since $P(Pat\mid Python)=P(Pat)=\frac{1}{2}$, both events are independent. Probabilities are calculated on (a).

**(e)**

Following the same reasoning as in (d), no, they aren't.

**(f)**

The same reasoning, no, they aren't.

Comment: thanks so much. so is $P(Pat∣Python)$ $(1/2+1/6)/(1/6)$?

Comment: @Csci319 I'd appreciate you choosing a Best answer, either mine or David K's in order to have this question as closed.

Answer (score 1):

I find sometimes it helps my intuition to suppose that the fractions
represent fractions of some particular quantity of things.
In this case, we might use "piece of code" as our "thing".

Unfortunately, 
the problem as posed here is severely misaligned with the way things
work in real life. This makes it more difficult to get a good intuition about how to understand what's going on here.

In real life, a "piece of code" is a flexible term. It might describe a
single expression or statement, a control block, a function, an entire file,
or something even larger. How do we identify the random "piece of code"?
If the pieces of code are of different sizes, with a different number of pieces
in each file of the project, how do we choose one at random so that every
piece is equally likely to be chosen? Or is the probability of choosing
pieces of code non-uniform? What do we do if we have a definition
of "piece of code" where one piece can contain or overlap several others?

Depending on what a "piece" of code is, and how we choose one, the likelihood
of choosing one of Pat's pieces may or may not have anything to do with who
wrote how much of the code. For example, we choose a single file at random,
but the output of each person is measured in lines of code. The chart could represent that Pat and Jon wrote three files each (one in each language)
while Maria wrote $100$ Javascript files, so Maria's code is most likely
to be chosen.

Moreover, depending on the nature of a software project, it's often very hard
to say who wrote a particular piece of code, because several people may have
edited the same lines of the same file.

So we have to make some assumptions about what all these words mean.
We have to assume that "piece of code" is defined in a way that makes it
easy to make a uniformly random selection from among them, 
that the authorship of each piece of code is known and is unambiguous,
and that the "fraction" of code written by each person is exactly 
proportional to the number of pieces they wrote.
Otherwise, the problem as posed is unsolvable.

So let's suppose that the project consists of many files, each file was written
by exactly one person, and we simply choose one file with uniform probability.

Having decided that, consider an even more concrete example:
suppose there are exactly $240$ files in the project.
The number is chosen because it makes all of the fractions in the table
realizable. The number of files written by each person in each language
(also the total number of files written by each person, and the total number
in each language) is shown in this table:
$$
\begin{array}{lcrrrrcr}
 &\quad& \mbox{C} & \mbox{C++} & \mbox{Python} & \mbox{JavaScript} &\quad& \mbox{total} \\
\\
\mbox{Pat}   && 50 & 30 & 40 & 0  && 120 \\
\mbox{Jon}   && 10 & 30 & 20 & 0  &&  60 \\
\mbox{Maria} &&  0 &  0 & 20 & 40 &&  60 \\
\\
\mbox{total} && 60 & 60 & 80 & 40 && 240
\end{array}$$

Now we can easily answer questions such as what is the probability that
a given piece of code was written by Pat, given that it was written in C++:
there are $60$ such files, and Pat wrote $30$ of them, exactly $\frac12$
of that total, so the probability is $\frac12$.

The point of all the above is not that you should solve all such problems
this way.
What you hopefully may do eventually is to refine your intuition about
joint probability distributions to the point where you can simply assume that
all these concrete definitions of the real-life objects involved in the
question have been chosen in such a way as to make sense, and solve the
problem in pure probabilities without thinking about how many actual
pieces of code there are or what a piece of code actually is.
Then you'll be able to apply such things as
the definition of independent events
and Bayes' Theorem more easily.

It might also be reassuring to know that if you're having difficulty
interpreting this word problem, it isn't entirely your fault.
The choice of the domain of the problem itself makes it harder to understand.